# jScrollPane 2.0 height problem in chrome

Tags: jquery, google-chrome, height, jscrollpane

I am using a div with class scroll-pane (height 100%) within an absolute positioned div. The scroll-pane div contains some text first, followed by an image and followed by some text again. The image height is set to 200px.
Problem is! If I view the scrollpane in Chrome (latest Version) I sometimes can scroll the complete content and sometimes, after refreshing the site in the browser, not. Not does mean that I can only see a part of the second text and not more. So the actual scrolling height shrinks. If I refresh again I might be able to see it all complete again and so on. It changes every time I refresh the browser. It only happens in Chrome.

Any idea what I can do to avoid that behavior? Thanks.....

UPDATE
It really got something to do with how the imports (js and css) are lined up in the header. You are right, the css got to be imported before the jscrollPane js but that also means that the image height need to come from one of the css stylesheets. You can not define the height right within the image tag in your markup. My solution was to create a class, for i.e. img200 (representing a height of 200px) in my stylesheet and that made the trick.
So here again what need to be done to make it work in Chrome or better webkit Browsers in general:
Set up a image height class in your stylesheet for images that are used within a scrollPane.
Include your stylesheet before!!!!! the javascript for jScrollPane.
Add the special height class to all pictures you include to a jScrollPane
That was it. Thanks again for your fast answer. Very cool.

**FINAL SOLUTION UPDATE!!!!!!!!!**
If you have pictures within a jScrollPane area you have to make sure the following in order to have it all displayed well in webkit browser, like Chrome or Safari. Otherwise it will cause height problems and only a part of your content will be visible.
***This is what you have to do:***
Make sure the line up of your css stylesheets and the jScrollPane javascript file is correct. The jScrollPane javascript file need to follow your css stylesheets and not the other way around! Also you have to add a height to each image that is included in the jScrollPane area. You can do this either by creating a css class or you can add the dimension as an attribute directly to the img in your html markup.
*If you keep that in mind it will do the trick.*

Comment: Thank you sooo much! That is exactly what I was searching for! Great answer! It was bothering me for long time. Just never to catch the problem. 'Images' styles... :| Well I'm going to make a jQuery now to grab all the styles of any image and add them separately to each img 'style' property. CIAO

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Did you also test in Safari? This sounds like an issue that occurs in Webkit when the javascript is included before the CSS in the head of the document:
http://jscrollpane.kelvinluck.com/faqs.html#webkit-broken

If that isn't the cause then it might be something related to the fact that you have an image in your scrollpane. You need to either include the width and height of the image (see http://jscrollpane.kelvinluck.com/image2.html) or autoReinitialise the pane (see http://jscrollpane.kelvinluck.com/image.html).

Hope it helps :)

Comment: Hi.I am very impressed by that quick help because that was my first question ever here. Actually you are right and I found out that after I posted my question.

Comment: I like the autoReinitialize option but I had to stay away from it because it made my whole scrollTo transitions very shaky. I couldn´t find a way to fix that.

Comment: It was shaky only in IE (work with IE8). Maybe someone got a solution for that, too.

Comment: Please view my UPDATE for my final solution. Sorry for that bite by bite comments but I still have to get used to that new portal that I never have used before.

Comment: Glad you found a solution. Interesting that adding the width and height directly on the image didn't work for you - I'm sure I have done that successfully before. Were you trying to add them as attributes or in a style tag?

Comment: @vitch
Actually I was under the impression that the dimension got to come from the css because the solution was all about the correct line up of css and js imports in the head section. That made me think it will not work to add the dimensions to the html img tag but I will try today again. Maybe the line up is important but dimensions can be added directly to the img tag also. Let you know later.
Cheers to London

Answer (score 3):

give the call to jscrollpane in `$(window).load` instead of `$(document).ready`

Comment: Note that the load event is deprecated for use since jQuery version 1.8. The new way is shown in [why $(window).load() is not working in jQuery?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38650372/1115360)

Answer (score 2):

I have also discovered that adding a css rule to .scroll-pane for line-height solves my height issues.

For example:

```
.scroll-pane {line-height: 1;}
```

or whatever line height your content may need.

I also discovered that if you use @font-face, jscrollpane may do the height calculation before your font has properly loaded, and therefore miscalculate.  I fixed this by adding the setting:

```
autoReinitialise: true
```

It runs on a timer though so use thoughtfully.

Answer (score 1):

If you have image inside your jScrollPane div area, simply define its width and height.

```
<div class="scroll-pane">
<img src="image.jpg" alt="" width="300" height="50" />
</div>
```

That will fix the jScrollPane's webkit bug. Oh and of course load the CSS before JS