# jScrollPane cutting off bottom of content

Tags: jquery, css, jscrollpane, jquery-jscrollpane

I'm using jScrollPane on a site I'm developing, and on all of the divs that use jScrollPane, the bottom of the div is hidden.

You can see the problem [here](http://woody.alchemycs.com/our-story/) or [here](http://woody.alchemycs.com/writing/book-4/).

It seems to me that the problem must be that my `.page-scroll` div is too tall, but making it shorter doesn't do any good.  I've messed with the heights of all the divs on the page (those created by me and those created by jScrollPane), and nothing seems to help.

Does anyone have any suggestions?

**EDIT**
MiniRagnarok found the answer, but I'll summarize it here so that you don't have to read through our whole conversation, if anyone else is having this problem.  I think that this thread: [jScrollPane 2.0 height problem in chrome](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3820632/jscrollpane-2-0-height-problem-in-chrome) actually answers it.  I think the issue is that the site uses @font-face, which renders the font after jScrollPane has decided how tall the page is.  So by adding `autoReinitialise: true` to the element, I was able to fix the problem.  And then MiniRagnarok found some silliness in my CSS that compounded the problem.  All better now!

Comment: Did you try the known issues [page](http://jscrollpane.kelvinluck.com/known_issues.html)?

Comment: Yep - nothing there helped.

Comment: What about [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6258178/bottom-content-cutoff-using-overflow-auto-and-jscrollpane)?

Comment: I ask because I tried viewing it in IE9 and it looked fine. When I looked in Chrome and FireFox, I couldn't scroll all the way to the bottom. It might be the order the javascript is firing or just the plugin itself.

Comment: That's an issue with dynamic content.  This content is static, so I don't think reinitializing will help.

Comment: Ha, that's funny!  For once, something that works in IE but not other browsers!

Comment: jQuery is firing in the right order.  If it were just the plugin itself, I imagine lots of other people would be having this problem (it's a pretty major problem that would make jScrollPane unusable).  I've used jScrollPane on other sites and not had this problem.  So I'm sure I've done something wrong, or there's something I can do to fix it.

Comment: It's weird, sometimes when I load it in Chrome, it will scroll all the way to the bottom.

Comment: I know you think it's an issue with dynamic content, but try it. I've come across many people saying the same thing. Like [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3820632/jscrollpane-2-0-height-problem-in-chrome).

Comment: I tried reinitializing, but that didn't fix it.  :(

Comment: Oh wait.... reinitializing sortof fixes it... you can now scroll all the way to the bottom of the content, but the bottom of the scrollbar is still cut off.  I guess that's better than nothing....

Comment: The cutoff is because of `top:15px;` to the Vertical Bar is pushing it down.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is two-fold. Remove `top:15px;` from the Vertical Bar and reinitialize jScrollPane.