# why $(window).load() is not working in jQuery?

Tags: jquery

I'm learning jQuery using visual studio and testing my code in Chrome browser. This is my HTML code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <script src="jquery-3.1.0.js"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(window).load(function () {
            alert("Window Loaded");
        });
    </script>
</head>
<body>

</body>
</html>
```

This is my solution explorer

[image: Solution Explorer]

Now why my browser doesn't alert "window Loaded"?

Comment: Yes, cause $(document).ready() is working.

Comment: windows load is hardly used why not use document ready statement ?

Comment: from the documentation i see that is deprecated from 1.8 you have version 3

Comment: I didn't know that, totally new and following a tutorial, is it backdated?

Comment: what do you mean by backdated?

Comment: Now i get it, in the tutorial they use jquery-1.11.2.js . Thats why it's not working here.

Answer (score 192, accepted):

You're using jQuery version 3.1.0 and the load event is deprecated for use since jQuery version 1.8. The load event is removed from [jQuery 3.0](https://api.jquery.com/load-event/). Instead you can use [on](http://api.jquery.com/on) method and bind the JavaScript [load event](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/load):

```
 $(window).on('load', function () {
      alert("Window Loaded");
 });
```

Answer (score 13):

In short, **the FIRST answer is the CORRECT one:**

```
$(window).on('load', function () {
  alert("Window Loaded.");
});
```

I have to write a whole answer separately since it's hard to add a comment so long to the second answer.

I'm sorry to say this, **but the second answer above doesn't work right.**

The following three scenarios will show my point:

**Scenario 1:** Before the following way was deprecated,

```
  $(window).load(function () {
     alert("Window Loaded.");
  });
```

if we execute the following two queries:

```
<script>
   $(window).load(function () {
     alert("Window Loaded.");
   }); 
 
   $(document).ready(function() {
     alert("Dom Loaded.");
   });
</script>,
```

**the alert (Dom Loaded.) from the second query will show first, and the one (Window Loaded.) from the first query will show later**, which is the way it should be.

**Scenario 2:** But if we execute the following two queries like the second answer above suggests:

```
<script>
   $(window).ready(function () {
     alert("Window Loaded.");
   }); 
 
   $(document).ready(function() {
     alert("Dom Loaded.");
   });
</script>,
```

**the alert (Window Loaded.) from the first query will show first, and the one (Dom Loaded.) from the second query will show later, which is NOT right.**

**Scenario 3:** On the other hand, if we execute the following two queries, we'll get the correct result:

```
<script>
   $(window).on("load", function () {
     alert("Window Loaded.");
   }); 
 
   $(document).ready(function() {
     alert("Dom Loaded.");
   });
</script>,
```

that is to say, **the alert (Dom Loaded.) from the second query will show first, and the one (Window Loaded.) from the first query will show later**, which is the **RIGHT** result.

That's why **the FIRST answer is the CORRECT one:**

```
$(window).on('load', function () {
  alert("Window Loaded.");
});
```

Comment: Your suggested order is not right. Scenario 3 as example show for me after many page refresh (F5) one time "DOM loaded" as first entry, another time "Window loaded" as first entry. Maybe that is because all images already in browser cache. There is no guarantee that "load" fires always as last part after "DOM loaded". Not in jQuery 3.6 and not in pure JS with addEventListener().

Answer (score 2):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
   $(window).ready(function () {
      alert("Window Loaded");
   });
</script>
```

Comment: Actually this is equivalent to $(document).ready(), see the notes about the [deprecation in jQuery 3](https://api.jquery.com/ready/): "the selection has no bearing on the behavior of the .ready() method".

Comment: This is NOT the equivalent of $(window).load

Comment: What's the difference?

Comment: Although this seems OK, it doesn't work right. I wrote answer below.

Comment: Yea, William's answer is better.

Answer (score 0):

in jquery-3.1.1

```
$("#id").load(function(){
//code goes here
});
```

will not work because load function is no more work

Answer (score 0):

I am using latest 3.6.1 jQuery and the document.ready and window.load were not executed in correct sequence; sometime document.ready used to execute after window.load.  Using below script the sequence of execution is working fine for me.

```js
//If you want the earliest event use native code (similar to document.ready function)
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function () {
    console.log("01. DOMContentLoaded");    
})

//If you want to trigger event after window load (after all assets are loaded)
window.addEventListener('load', function () {
    console.log("02. Window onload event"); 
});
```