# preloader: how to delete current loader div to show content div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a problem with my preloader. It not faded out, and show the content.
This is my HTML, JS ,and CSS code:
HTML:

```
<body>    
   <div class="preload" id="preload"></div>
   <div class="content hidden" id="content"></div>
<body>
```

JS:

```
$(window).load(function() {
    $("#preload").delay(700).fadeOut("slow");
    $("#content").removeClass("hidden");
});
```

CSS:

```
.hidden{
    visibility: hidden;
}
.preload{
    width  : 100%;
    height : 100%;
    top    : 0;
    left   : 0;
    z-index: 1;
    bottom : 0;
    position  : fixed;
    background: #ff1a1a;
}
.loader-frame{
    margin  : auto;
    position: relative;
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: It could be the classes you're using.  Since you didn't post the css, we cannot help you. :(

Comment: Possible duplicate of [why $(window).load() is not working in jQuery?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38650315/why-window-load-is-not-working-in-jquery)

Comment: i think you need to use on() method

Comment: i think it's may help you: https://github.com/bjayanta/Simple-Preloader

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you just need to change in js file. like:

```
$(window).on('load', function(){
    $('#preload').delay(700).fadeOut('slow', function(){
        $("#content").removeClass("hidden");
    });

});
```