# Insert html after a hidden element using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm trying to insert some html after an element in a section that is initially set to `display: none;`. I'm using the following:

```
$(window).load(function(e) {
 $(".tribe-tickets-meta-field-header").after('<span>Hello World</span>');
})
```

I can get it to work when the element is visible but not when it is hidden. Is there a way that I can insert the html while the target element is hidden?

I'm not sure how to reproduce the page I'm working with as it is generated by a CMS. Below is a screenshot of the markup.

[html output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ioAxg.png)

Comment: Nothing in that code cares whether the element is hidden or visible (proof: https://jsfiddle.net/9ap5d3rs/), it will insert the span after it. Please update your question with a [mcve] demonstrating the problem, ideally a **runnable** one using Stack Snippets (the `[<>]` toolbar button; [here's how to do one](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-do-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do-tha)).

Comment: Seems to be working fine for me. https://jsfiddle.net/5a5scv4p/1/

Comment: Side note: To make your code compatible with jQuery v3, suggest using `.on("load", ...` rather than `.load(...` (the latter shortcut is removed in v3). Also recommend not using the `window` `load` event unless you *really* need to wait until after all images and other resources have finished loading.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [why $(window).load() is not working in jQuery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38650315/why-window-load-is-not-working-in-jquery)

Answer (score 0):

If the element is display: none; it does not exist in DOM tree, so we cannot use append another element after it. So if you want to do this, you have to check the element after the element with display:none to use jQuery.prepend(). Hope this help.

Comment: "If the element is display: none; it does not exist in DOM tree" why? I just added element after with question code in display: none element.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. Unfortunately, using `jQuery.prepend()` didn't work either. Based on other comments, I'm guessing that something else is at play with the way the page is loading.