# Jquery load is only working once on first click

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to create a video slideshow, operated by next/prev buttons, however, only the first click event works. It is important that the videos autoplay, only the first video plays once loaded, and the next/prev buttons should start/restart the next/prev video from the beginning.

I have tried to do this with jquery and .load(), in order to prevent all other videos playing in background on load. Currently, it works on the first click, but any event on the next button is not registered.

Here is a snippet:

```js
var pos = 0,
    slides = $('.slide'),
    /*navl = $('.left'),*/
    numOfSlides = slides.length;

function nextSlide(){
    stopCurrentVideo();
    slides.eq(pos).animate({leftq:'-100%'},0);
    pos = pos >= numOfSlides-1 ? 0 : ++pos;
    slides.eq(pos).css({left:'100%'}).animate({left:0},0);

}

function previousSlide(){
    stopCurrentVideo();
    slides.eq(pos).animate({left:'100%'},0);
    pos = pos == 0 ? numOfSlides-1 : --pos;
    slides.eq(pos).css({left:'-100%'}).animate({left:0},0);
    /*navl.eq(pos).css({display:'none'});*/
}

function stopCurrentVideo(){
    $('.slider-video:eq('+pos+')').load()
    .siblings('.overlay-content').show();
}

$('.left').click(previousSlide);
$('.right').click(nextSlide);

    $('#next1.navigation.right').on('click', function() {
  $('#video-sequence-2').load('https://cbtesting.s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/video-sequencing-1.html #video2');
 $('#next1.navigation.right').hide();
});

            $('#next2.navigation.right').on('click', function() {
  $('#video-sequence-3').load('https://cbtesting.s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/video-sequencing-1.html #video3');
 /*$('button').hide();*/
});

    $('#next3.navigation.right').on('click', function() {
  $('#video-sequence-4').load('https://cbtesting.s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/video-sequencing-1.html #video4');
 /*$('button').hide();*/
});
```

```css
html {
    font-size: 16px;
}
body {
    font-family: PT Sans, sans-serif;
    color: #333333;
    line-height: auto;
}

.video-slider {
    max-width: 1920px;
    height: 1080px;
    width:100%;
    margin:0 auto;
    /*background: #444;*/
    position: relative;
    overflow: hidden;
}
.slide {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    text-align: center;
    overflow: hidden;
}
.slide:first-child{
    left: 0;
}

.overlay-content {
    background: #f8f9fa;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 40%;
    right: 3%;
    height: 400px;
    width: 400px;
    opacity: 0.8;
}

#navigation{
    background: none;
    position: relative;
    padding-top: 5%;
    height: 5%;
    width: 24%;
    float: right;
}

.overlay-content p, h3{
    font-family: PT Sans, sans-serif;
    position: relative;
    font-size:16px;
    text-align: left;
    line-height: auto;
    color:#333333;
    padding:5%;
}

.overlay-content p:first-child{
    font-family: PT Sans, sans-serif;
    position: relative;
    font-size:16px;
    text-align: left;
    line-height: auto;
    color:#333333;
    padding:5%;
}

.overlay-content h3{
    padding-bottom: 1%;
    font-size:18px;
}

.navigation.left{
    position: inherit;
    text-align: left;
    display: inline-block;
    /* bottom: 10%; */
    left: 8%;
    cursor: pointer;
    opacity: 1;
    color: black;

}
.navigation.right{
    position: inherit;
    display: inline-block;
    text-align: right;
    /* bottom: 10%; */
    right: 8%;
    cursor: pointer;
    opacity: 1;
    color: black;
}

video{
    max-height: 100%;
    max-width: 100%;
    /*pointer-events: none;*/
}

video::-webkit-media-controls {
  display: none;
}

video::-webkit-media-controls-play-button {
    display: none;

}
video::-webkit-media-controls-volume-slider {
    display: none;
}
video::-webkit-media-controls-mute-button {
    display: none;
}
video::-webkit-media-controls-timeline {
    display: none;
}
video::-webkit-media-controls-current-time-display{
    display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"></script>
<div class="video-slider">
    <!-- SLIDE 1 -->
    <div class="slide">
        <video class="slider-video" id="split01" autoplay controls="false">
            <source src="https://cbtesting.s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/vid1.mp4" type="video/mp4" />
        </video>
        <div class="overlay-content animated fadeIn">
        <div id="navigation">
            <div class="navigation right" id="next1">Next</div>
            <!-- <div class="navigation left">Previous</div> -->
        </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <!-- SLIDE 2 -->
    <div class="slide">
        <div id="video-sequence-2"></div>
    </div>
    <!--SLIDE 3-->

    <div class="slide">
        <div id="video-sequence-3"></div>
    </div>
    
        <div class="slide">
        <div id="video-sequence-4"></div>
    </div>
    
</div>
```

And the external html page looks like this:

```
   <video class="slider-video" id="split02" controls="false">
            <source src="https://cbtesting.s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/vid2.mp4" type="video/mp4" />
        </video>
        <div class="overlay-content animated fadeIn">
            <h3>Headline02</h3>
        <p>
        2. - Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
        </p>
        <div id="navigation">
            <div class="navigation right" id="next2">Next</div>
            <!-- <div class="navigation left">Previous</div> -->
        </div>
    </div>  
</div>



<!-- VIDEO 3 -->

<div id="video3">
        <video class="slider-video" id="split03" controls="false">
            <source src="https://cbtesting.s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/vid1.mp4" type="video/mp4" />
        </video>
        <div class="overlay-content animated fadeIn">
            <h3>Headline03</h3>
        <p>
        3. - Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
        </p>
        <div id="navigation">
            <div class="navigation right" id="next3">Next</div>
            <div class="navigation left">Previous</div>
        </div>
</div>
</div>
```

etc

I am trying to restart the videos whether the user clicks prev or next. There are no error messages when trying to inspect the 2nd next button.

Any help really appreciated!

Comment: Show the jquery code instead. And maybe it helps you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38650315/why-window-load-is-not-working-in-jquery/38650372#38650372

Comment: Please include all relevant code here on Stack Overflow, preferably in a [mre]. You can likely use [Stack Snippets](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/358992/215552) to do so.

Comment: @HereticMonkey Thanks - it's updated now